# How to allow access to nodes with terms that match the terms in a user profile?

Tags: 7, users

I try to create a site based on D7. I have an issue and I don't have any idea how can I solve it.

A user should have two term reference fields in the user's profile. And a node should have the same node reference fields to the same taxonomy vocabularies. If a user's profile contains the same terms as the terms in a node, then the user has read access to the node.

For this issue, a very suitable module is the [Access By Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/abt) module, but this module uses OR-logic, instead I need AND-logic. In other words, the user should only have access to nodes which have both of these TWO terms, not only one of these terms.

Any help?

Comment: 1. I mean only read access.
2. Dozens terms

Comment: Please review my edit of your question. Feel free to furhter refine/correct it where needed, or just perfor a rolback if you don't like my edit at all.

Comment: Thx for the corrections and I'm so sorry for my English level.

Comment: You could try to override the Access By Term's function `function abt_node_grants($account, $op) {` in abt.module with your own function in your custom module and add the logic to make sure both terms are present. You'd have to make sure your custom function fires after ABT though.

Comment: Great idea, now I will try do it.